# The page changes but sees the old page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Here is my code:

```js
await page.goto("https://github.com/");
await frame1.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("#ajaxContent > a").click());
await delay(10000);

const url = await page.url();
console.log(url);
const iframeHandle2 = await page.$("frame[name='frame2']"); // Change the selector
console.log(iframeHandle2);
const frame2 = await iframeHandle2.contentFrame();
```

Clicking on a link opens a new tab, but when I try to get a link to the page, it brings up the link to the old tab.

`console.log(url)` This result is github.com but

```js
await frame1.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("#ajaxContent > a").click());
```

After this line I have open new tab how can I reach url or elements new tab?